# If $X$ is a paracompact Hausdorff space, then so is Y

Tags: general-topology

It is suggested as the exercise 41.8(b) in Munkres. I tried to prove this and I think I used all the assumption, but it doesn't work. The precise statement is the following.

Let $p : X \rightarrow Y$ be a perfect map. Show that if X is a paracompact Hausdorff space, then so is Y. Below argument is my trial.

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an open covering of $Y$. Then $\{p^{-1}(A) : A \in \mathcal{A}\}$ is an open covering of $X$. We know that every paracompact Hausdorff space is normal, so $X$ is regular. Hence, there is a closed refinement $\mathcal{B}$ of $\{p^{-1}(A) : A \in \mathcal{A}\}$ that covers $X$ and is locally finite. Since $p$ is closed map(b.c perfect map), $\{p(B) : B \in \mathcal{B}\}$ is a closed covering of $Y$ by surjectiveness of $p$. We'll show this collection of sets is actually closed refinement of $\mathcal{A}$ that covers $Y$ and is locally finite. It suffices to show that $Y$ is paracompact because $Y$ is regular by exercise 31.6.

First, we'll show the given set is a refinement. Choose any $p(B)$ where $B \in \mathcal{B}$. Since $\mathcal{B}$ is a refinement of $\{p^{-1}(A) : A \in \mathcal{A}\}$, there is $A \in \mathcal{A}$ s.t $B \subset p^{-1}(A)$. Thus $p(B) \subset A$. This shows the given set is a refinement of $\mathcal{A}$

Second, we have to show that it is locally finite. Let $y \in Y$. By perfectness, $p^{-1}(\{y\})$ is compact. For each $x \in p^{-1}(\{y\})$, there is a nbd $U_x$ of x that intersects only finitely many elements of $\mathcal{B}$. Note that $\{U_x\}$ covers compact set $p^{-1}(\{y\})$. So there is $x_1,\cdots, x_n$ s.t $p^{-1}(\{y\}) \subset U_{x_1} \cup \cdots \cup U_{x_n}$. Let $U = U_{x_1} \cup \cdots \cup U_{x_n}$. Note that $U$ intersects only finitely many elements of $\mathcal{B}$. Then by hint of exercise 31.6, there is a nbd $W$ of $y$ s.t $p^{-1}(W) \subset U$. I hope $W$ intersects only finitely many elements of $\{p(B) : B \in \mathcal{B}\}$ But I cannot proceed anymore.
Did I come in the wrong direction?

Comment: Try replacing $W$ with $W\setminus f(\bigcup\{B\mid B\cap U=\emptyset\})$. This set is open since $\mathcal{B}$ is locally-finite and $f$ is closed. It contains $y$, and meets $f(B)$ only if $B$ meets $U$.